# Cannot fix wonky vertical Feynman diagrams created with tikz

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I am struggling to get the diagrams I create with tikz to 'spread out' correctly. I thought it could be an issue with the environment of my main work or the text being either side of it etc so I tried creating a new overleaf tex file with nothing in it but title etc and the diagram itself. It still comes out wonky! I took the code directly from this guide [Feynman diagrams with TikZ](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05437.pdf), shown below is the full code for the overleaf tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\title{FeynmanDiagrams}
\author{ciara}
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\feynmandiagram [vertical'=a to b] {
i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
-- [fermion] a
-- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)]
-- [anti fermion] b
-- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
};

\end{document}
```

And the actual output I get is:

[image: A wonky feynman diagram]

Does anyone know what's going wrong? I'm also happy to switch to a different package for making the diagram if there's one that might be easier/behave better for vertical diagrams like this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the TeX.SE.
From this site: http://www.luatex.org/
`LuaTeX` is an extended version of `pdfTeX` using `Lua` as an embedded scripting language. The `LuaTeX` project's main objective is to provide an open and configurable variant of `TeX` while at the same time offering downward compatibility. From the user perspective we have `pdfTeX` as stable and more or less frozen **8 bit engine**, `XeTeX` as unicode input and font aware engine using libraries for font handling, and `LuaTeX` as engine that is programmable and delegates as much as possible to `Lua`, with the objective to keep the core engine lean and mean. Each engine has its benefits and drawbacks. In this case you should to use `LuaLaTeX`. In fact you will have the correct output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\title{FeynmanDiagrams}
\author{ciara}
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{center}
    \feynmandiagram [vertical'=a to b] {
i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
-- [fermion] a
-- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)]
-- [anti fermion] b
-- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
};
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]